# Central limit theorem: What is the probability than more than 36 randomly chosen songs are required to fill a program which is 76 minutes long?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

I am a little stumped by what this question is asking.

A large playlist consists of songs with times which have mean 2 minutes ten seconds and standard deviation 15 seconds.
What is the probability than more than 36 randomly chosen songs are required to fill a program which is 76 minutes long?

Would the equation I have to use to find Z be (76 - 2.167(36))/(.25*6)? Than subtract the z-value from 1? I am not sure that I am doing this right

Answer (score 2):

Find the MGF of $X_1+....+X_{36}$ which will be distributed normally with something like $N(72m,1.5m)$, standardize..ie$(76-72)/1.5$, and take out your tables.

Comment: Thank you but one question how did you get 72?

Comment: The sum of the MGFs, is simply the product if the 36 MGFs. $Mgf_x(t)=\exp(\mu(t) + (t^2\sigma^2)/2$. So clearly multiply 36 of these together will give $36\mu(t)$. Same idea to get the variance.